# Is there any historical evidence that Britishers interpolated Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, history, interpolation

For many years, there is a lot of influence of British in India.

> East India Company    1612–1757
>
> Company rule in India  1757–1858
>
> British Raj    1858–1947
>
> Partition of India  1947
>
> [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidencies_and_provinces_of_British_India)

Is there any historical evidence that British people interpolated any of Hindu Scripture during 1612-1947?

Comment: A good question but  there  is a very similar question already present here. So it's quite possible that yours is Duplicate. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/were-hindu-scriptures-tampered-with-by-the-british

Comment: Well they didn't go that far. They just said all mythology.  Easy work for them

Comment: Yes bhavishya puran mentions about queen Victoria

Comment: They have created something called sailopanishad in praise of jesus