# Do we have complete knowledge/texts of Shaivism & Vaishnavism?

Tags: scripture, manuscripts

Bharata is a country where many [invasion](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-chronological-order-of-foreign-invasion-of-India) took place: Alexander, Chengiz Khan, Mohammed Bin Qasim, Timur, Nadir Shah, Ahmed Shah Abdali, and British etc.

And, many of them tried to destroyed our thriving heritage including precious scriptures. It is said that British maligned many scriptures with intention of ruining our spiritual culture (which they succeeded). Also, they took away many scripts, scrolls etc. with them and they are kept in the various museums across United Kingdoms.

From time to time, different forms of Shiva and Vishnu imparted knowledge in different forms and domains to different sages, rishis, brahmins, rashtriyas etc. for well-being of humanity. And, I suppose when storing of scripts in the form of written knowledge was practiced, we wrote it down all the acquired knowledge and pass it down as inheritance for new generations to come.

So, currently, if not original, do we have all texts or knowledge in good condition and without tempering with us or we have knowledge gap?

I am looking for authentic answer.

Comment: This looks like a very broad question.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion I am not asking for list of all books, but whereabouts of scriptures in form of texts. Like, yes a particular ashram has all texts or something on similar lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Were Hindu scriptures tampered with by the British?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/were-hindu-scriptures-tampered-with-by-the-british)

Comment: @sv. I read the question and answer you pointed out, but my concern is about someone or some ashram or institute possessing all the related texts. Like what if, someone wants to read all knowledge imparted by Mahadev. Do we have it?

Comment: As others have commented your question is too broad and this part is self-contradictory: "So, currently, if not original, do we have all texts or knowledge in good condition and without tampering, with us or do we have a knowledge gap?" On one hand you claim scriptures were tampered other hand you ask if we still have the originals.

Comment: @sv. I guess there is some misunderstanding. I say, "if not original" meaning I assume that Britishers took some original text with them or destroyed it. So, yes I am not answering my own question.

Comment: e. g. Someone might write an answer that yes Delhi University has all texts/knowledge in their concern department or someone in banaras has it.

Comment: It is like receiving authentic confirmation in form of answer that yes we have we have knowledge and text with us.

Comment: We do not have all scriptures particularly the Tantras. Several of them were destroyed by Muslim invaders. Tantras are the ones among all scriptures which are affected the most. Because they are meant to be kept secret and propagated secretly and on top of that those destructions. So, their preservation was not sufficiently done. I don't have enough reference to write an answer though.@UbiBhatt

Comment: @Rickross so, I wonder how Annamalai university provides specialization in shivism (and vishavism). Trantra is the real science, it is the knowledge that binds idol worship and spirituality or gunna with nirgunna.

Comment: Well, I don't know about that university but obviously everyone of us have to manage with whatever that is available to us right now. However, we do have some texts that quote portions from lost Tantras. But, it is a fact that a lot of Tantras has been lost now. @UbiBhatt